# Week problems in php

Tags: php, date

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

`strftime('%YW%U', strtotime('2013W37')) = '2013W36'`

I have some code that relies on that not happening. Any alternatives?

I'm using PHP 5.4.9 on OSX

Comment: what do you want to happen?

Comment: Well, I suppose he wants `2013W37` to be the result. I'll bet a beer it's a time zone issue (the date moving a couple of hours into the previous week)

Comment: we can all guess, I'll wait and see if he bothers to answer.

Comment: Having '2013W37' as the result is exactly what I wanted it to be the result, but I see now my not paying attention to ISO standards was the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong format character.

The string `"2013W37"` is interpreted by `strtotime` according to ISO-8601, in which weeks start on Monday, and the first week of the year is the one containing at least 4 days in the new year and is numbered 1.

But `%U` gets you the week number of the year in which the week starts on Sunday and the first week of the year is week 0.

What you want is `%YW%V`, because `%V` is the ISO-8601 week number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PHP 5.4 why not use the `Datetime();` class.

Something like this.

```
$date = new Datetime('2013W37');

print $date->format('Y\WW');
```

This will output 2013W37;

Also by using the Datetime() class you are opening up the power of OOP as well as a plethora of date math functions.

You can read more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Note that the `DateTime` constructor uses the same parsing process as `strtotime`, and `DateTime::format` uses the same formatting specifiers as `date`, so this answer also works without the OOP. The key point is that not all week-of-year definitions work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime` uses ISO standard](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) when parsing this string so You should use `%V` for week number.

PS: But for some reason `%V` doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Ooh, I'd never seen that documentation page before. It took me a while to understand what I was looking at, but that's a really handy reference. I always thought `strtotime`, and its OO cousins, were just "magic" ;)

Comment: There are 3 more pages in documentation on that subject.